# A rational function with no poles is regular

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, divisors-algebraic-geometry

> If $f$ is a nonzero rational function on a locally Noetherian normal scheme and $f$ has no poles, show that $f$ is regular.

The hint is to use algebraic Hartogs' lemma which is the following

Suppose A is a integrally closed Noetherian integral domain. Then
$$ A = \bigcap_{ p \text{ }\text{codimension 1}} A_p   $$

I can prove this when then scheme is an affine normal scheme, but I don't know how to prove the general case.

Comment: General schemes are covered by affine schemes. Does this not immediately give the result?